# Joomla 2.5 render com_content component output

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

is it possible to render Joomla content from external script? For example I have some html string, which I want to pass to `com_content` component, to make all content plugin and module features available. I think I should use `JDocumentRendererComponent` class. Code in my external file:

```
<?php

require_once ('framework.php'); //loading joomla framework

jimport('joomla.document.html.renderer.component');

$contentHtml = '<p>Some content html</p>';

echo JDocumentRendererComponent::render('com_content',array(),$contentHtml);

?>
```

What I get is error on the last line:

`Fatal error: Class 'JDocumentRendererComponent' not found...`

What Im doing wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: That's all you did? You didn't instantiate an application?

Comment: @Elin, I did instantiate the application. It is here: require_once('framework.php'). I do not provide this file content, but initialization works perfectly well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found other solution for my question. The job can be also done by content plugin events (triggers). The piece of code from `components/com_content/views/article/view.html.php`:

```
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('content');
$results = $dispatcher->trigger('onContentPrepare', array ('com_content.article', &$item, &$this->params, $offset));

$item->event = new stdClass();
$results = $dispatcher->trigger('onContentAfterTitle', array('com_content.article', &$item, &$this->params, $offset));
$item->event->afterDisplayTitle = trim(implode("\n", $results));

$results = $dispatcher->trigger('onContentBeforeDisplay', array('com_content.article', &$item, &$this->params, $offset));
$item->event->beforeDisplayContent = trim(implode("\n", $results));

$results = $dispatcher->trigger('onContentAfterDisplay', array('com_content.article', &$item, &$this->params, $offset));
$item->event->afterDisplayContent = trim(implode("\n", $results));
```

So we can actually make an object from our string and pass it to these triggers. As a result we are getting content rendered like an article, with its major functionality.

Some more info about it:

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/create-plugin/content-plugin-events
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/joomla-dev-cms/VZVurjiZWIs/9Vr45KS2LTMJ

Answer (score 0):

It's because you haven't included the Joomla framework to the external script. Use the below code. This will ensure that the Joomla! environment is loaded correctly

```
/* Initialize Joomla framework */
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
/* Required Files */
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
/* To use Joomla's Database Class */
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'libraries'.DS.'joomla'.DS.'factory.php' );
/**************************************************/
// Your code starts here...
// Remember that the Site application isn't running, so you cannot access $mainframe or any of its methods.
/**************************************************/
```

`JDocumentRendererComponent` Class is located in located in /libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/component.php if you correct load the framework everything should work fine.

Comment: Im loading Joomla environment here: require_once('framework.php'). I do not provide this file content, but anyway the Joomla framework is loaded perfectly.

Comment: My application initialization is pretty much the same as yours. In the same script (not pasted the code in this example) Im loading Joomla db methods like: JFactory::getDbo() and etc. And it works. So I assume that framework is loaded correctly.

Comment: What version of the platform are you running?  JDocumentRendererComponent doesn't exist in the current platform but it did exist in 11.3.

Comment: @Elin: Yes, the function is correct, I can navigate to it in my IDE (CTRL + MouseClick)