# Render k2 article in a custom component

Tags: joomla, k2

I'm beginner in joomla and I've written a custom component for joomla and I want link a K2 article to my content. In other words I want

- In backend Go to in my component settings and choose the article from the k2 article's list.
- In frontend when it's shows I  must see My content + article

I use joomla 3.x.

Any suggestion how to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Custom form field type** to create a custom form field for K2 article list for you custom component. For more information you can refer this documentation :

[Creating a custom form field type](https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type)

Hope this information will be helpful for you.

Comment: Ok, for selection the  article, but  can I render the article in the frontend  together to my content?

Comment: You can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119573/joomla-2-5-render-com-content-component-output